# class not found : com.android.graphics.CanvasView

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, paint

I use this [library](https://github.com/Korilakkuma/CanvasView) in my project.but i have an error. class 'com.android.graphics.CanvasView' not found.have error.how i can fix it? thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<com.android.graphics.CanvasView
    android:id="@+id/canvas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in java code :

```
package com.example.falah.paint2;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;



public class DrawActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CanvasView canvas;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_draw);

    canvas = (CanvasView)this.findViewById(R.id.canvas);
}
}
```

Comment: please help me.

Comment: How have you included the library in your project? Do you Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: i use android studio.how i can add lib in my project?? i use code in project

Comment: One easy way is to create a file named CanvasView.java in your project and simply copy paste content from here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Korilakkuma/CanvasView/master/CanvasView/app/src/main/java/com/android/graphics/CanvasView.java

Comment: thanks for your answer.but i try this idea and it not work.when run project .. hav an error.  'android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.android.graphics.CanvasView'

Comment: Did you change the package name at the start of the CanvasView.java file to match the package structure as per where you copied the file in your projcet?

Comment: yes.Please help rather than ask questions perplexing

Comment: I won't be able to help you if I don't know what is going on in your computer. By the InflateException that you got it is most probable that you havent changed the package name in the CanvasView or you havent changed the layout file with the new package name of the CanvasView. Please post the layout file where you use this, the CanvasView class that you copied including the package name.

Comment: In the layout file you need to use com.example.falah.paint2.CanvasView instead of com.android.graphics.CanvasView if you have the CanvasView file in the same package as your MainActivity.

Comment: it's worked,thanks

Comment: Please consider upvoting and accepting my answer I posted as per our discussion here if it helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussions in the comments,

The owner of this repository does not have this library hosted on any service like JitPack or JCenter, else adding this library should be simply be adding a single line of code in your app level build.gradle file.

For now you can either download the code from their repository [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Korilakkuma/CanvasView/master/CanvasView/app/src/main/java/com/android/graphics/CanvasView.java) and paste it in a file named CanvasView.java

You will need to update the package name accordingly in both the CanvasView.java and the layout file where you use com.android.graphics.CanvasView and replace it with com.example.falah.paint2.CanvasView

Happy to help! Happy coding!

Comment: i have question! how i can use the setMode() in project ?? when i use it in eraser.onClickListener() it dont change

Comment: Maybe you can post this as another question. Also, I haven't used this library so...

Answer (score 1):

If anybody still stuck with this dependency,
[here](https://jitpack.io/#infotech-group/CanvasView/1.0.0) is the link for dependency

OR

Add this in your project level gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

And this in your app level gradle:

```
dependencies {
        implementation 'com.github.infotech-group:CanvasView:1.0.0'
}
```